# Windows phone 8.1 Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly not available

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am using reflection to register default instances for inversion of control. I need to scan all loaded assemblies and then iterate through each type and register. The problem is that in my visual studio code file I do not have the method `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` or any other methods that I would normally expect.

Why is this happening. My code should look like this:

```
foreach (var type in (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (type.IsClass && !type.IsAbstract)
    {
       //registers the type for an interface it implements
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get executing assembly in WinRT as you have discovered - but you can get type in "your assembly" - `typeof(AnyTypeInYourAssembly).GetTypeInfo().Assembly`

Answer (score 0):

I researched into this more, and it turns out the problem lies in the fact that Windows Phone 8.1 applications have the same restrictions as WinRT applications. There is no GetExecutingAssembly method for WinRT runtime.

You are forced with workarounds.